# Riddle: Spot the serious bug in this bubble sort implementation

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

(No, this isn't a homework assignment, I just found the bug and thought it might be useful to share it here)

```
import java.util.List;

public class BubbleSorter {

    public <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
        while (true) {
            boolean didWork = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; ++i) {
                if (list.get(i).compareTo(list.get(i + 1)) > 0) {
                    swap(list, i, i + 1);
                    didWork = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!didWork)
                return;
        }
    }

    private static <T> void swap(List<T> list, int i, int j) {
        T tmp = list.get(i);
        list.set(i, list.get(j));
        list.set(j, tmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the votes to close? Do you want me to edit the title to read "What is the serious bug in this implementation?" instead ?

Comment: Looks fine to me. That must be a hell of the bug.

Comment: @Nikita - ping me if you want a hint.

Comment: @ripper234 Is it a real bug in the algo or is it that the list can be unmodifiable and the `set` method won't work?

Comment: @ripper: The votes to close are because this isn't a code review site. We're not going to debug your code for you. You show us what YOU'VE done to find the problem and we can help with any specific issues you're having. You need to tell us why you think there's a bug in the first place.

Comment: I hope your external code prevents null elements from being added to the list.

Comment: @Falmarri - He pointed out that he has ALREADY found the problem:)

Comment: @RD, I assume there's no null objects. At this rate, I think I'd better post the solution to this before someone closes the question...

Comment: @Petar - it's an algorithm bug.

Comment: i vote to close it, it looks like homework! (just kidding, however since you already have 2 close votes this question will be closed soon, your best chance to keep it alive is repost it under different name). just saying, but since you already got the answer it doesnt matter :)

Comment: @01 - well, I stirred a discussion on this and made some people think - I don't care if it's closed (I bet it will be reopend anyway). I enjoyed solving this problem, and I hope some of you have as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a bug in the strictest sense, but doing `break;` when you find inversion gives your sorting `O(n^3)` complexity, which is hardly desirable. `break` can just be removed.

Comment: This is the bug I meant. I just wrote this code as warmup to writing a quicksort implementation and verifying my unit tests work. Then I started sorting medium-sized lists and saw the code was taking forever to sort them...

Comment: Yeah, not really a bug, but a major inefficiency.  (Not that bubble sort is all that efficient when it's done correctly anyway, but this is just CPU cycle gluttony.)  I noticed that "bug" but kept on staring at the code thinking there was supposed to be a bug that would break the sort. :-D

Answer (score 0):

The `swap` should be setting j, not i+1.

Comment: Not really a bug _in this case_ because j always equals i+1. This is just something missed in refactoring the code. There's a much more serious bug hidden here.

Comment: But thanks for spotting anyway - edited the question to remove this.

Comment: !! Oh, right :-) That's a bug in the swap function, but *not* the sort function …